# Make application / service priority really high

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, networking, keyboard, mouse

I am using two Ubuntu computers, I use this [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) application to share mouse and keyboard. However when the Synergy server computer is using peak CPU usage, the mouse pointer gets stiff. How do I make the Synergy app high in priority that it will be prioritized to be process at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the Synergy command from the Terminal through `nice`, like so:

```
nice --adjustment=-20 Synergy [arguments]
```

When setting the adjustment parameter, a lower value means a higher priority.  Possible priority values are between -20 and 19.  You will have to make sure you replace the `Synergy` above with the correct path to launch it.

Comment: When I run with 'nice' the UI looks like old Windows 98, although this does not matter to me, what does it mean?

Comment: It is possible that your usual startup sequence is passing different parameters to Synergy than you did on the command-line.  How have you been starting Synergy?

Comment: If I run '$ synergy' from command line it works fine, but anyway what I wanted to know is, is this a performance things that themes was stripped off

Comment: I do not know...